# How to clear ehcache without server restart

Tags: java, tomcat5.5

Though I guess it's highly unlikely - but is there any way to clear the ehcache without restarting the server? I need to clear the cache for some testing - I cannot change the code and cannot afford to restart server at multiple times.

PS: I am using apache-tomcat-5.5.25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JavaMelody](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody) can do this -- add it to your tomcat instance.